# how to fetch data from two tables(one-to-one) in cakephp2.x

Tags: cakephp, join, model, cakephp-2.0

i have 2 tables first name is inventories and second name is inventory_categories in inventories table have some fields

id,name ,inventory_category_id

in inventory_categories table have

```
 id,category_name
```

now i want fetch data from both table and want to show in inventory listing page 
and i have also create inventory model

```
<?php 
  class Inventory extends AppModel{  

  var $name = 'Inventory'; 

  var $hasOne = array("InventoryCategory");

  }
?>
```

another model is InventoryCategory

```
<?php 
 class InventoryCategory extends AppModel{  

  var $name = 'InventoryCategory'; 

  var $belongsto = array("Inventory");

 }
?>
```

please help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you define key(primary/foreign) relationship properly, you will get below code in your Inventory Controller index function.

```
$this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['InventoryCategory'] 
        ];
```

And your Inventory table have code as below

```
    $this->hasOne('InventoryCategory', [
        'foreignKey' => 'id'
    ]);
```

For printing values in index page

```
 foreach ($inventories as $inventory): 
        echo $inventory->inventory_category->id;
 endforeach
```

Comment: but i have only define id column as a primery key in both table

Comment: @netxperia then foreignkey will be id

Comment: i am so confuse can u explain sir

Comment: @netxperia under Model/Table you have InventoryTable.php or InventariesTable.php